# How to combine select, label, where and date functions in Google Sheets

Tags: sql, date, google-sheets, label, google-query-language

I have most of this query working, where it's pulling in what I want by the correct date, but I just can't seem to work the Label function in correctly to rename the columns.

Here is the functioning query:
=QUERY(Results!A1:I500,"SELECT B, A, F, G, H, I  WHERE D = 'project' and B >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)

I've tried adding in Label B 'Date' in various places but it always breaks the query and since I have only been doing this for an afternoon largely with the help of google, I figured maybe someone else knows better.

Comment: You can find the correct order of the query clauses in the official documentation - https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#language-clauses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(Results!A1:I500,
 "select B,A,F,G,H,I 
  where D = 'project' 
    and B >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  label B'date'", 1)
```